# Variable "cluster" to count factorial in c#

Tags: c#, .net, variables, cluster-computing, factorial

Trying to count **factorial** of a big number, for example **1000!**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UInt64 fact = 1;

            for (UInt64 i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(fact); //returns 0, due to overflow UInt64, max fact is 56!

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

So i ask, if there is some way to **join more variables to cluster**, so i can make really large variable to store "big" number.

Comment: can use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) for even bigger numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930611/working-with-very-large-integers-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). This type can store integers of arbitrary size, until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4 
[BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) will do what you want.

[Big integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp) may be of more interest as well since it is a very similar question (well, more a very similar answer).